# Does spring-security 3.1 support spring-security-oauth (for oauth2)? Is there a reference?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am working with an app that uses spring-security 3.0 and oauth2 using spring-security-oauth-1.0.0.M3.  It works fine.  But it looks like migrating to spring-security 3.1 will not be trivial.  I have been unable to find confirmation that the oauth module is still supported.

For example, the oauth tutorial mentions 3.0 not 3.1:

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/wiki/tutorial

And I have encountered a problem similar to the Mar 4, 2012 comment in the following discussion when I attempt to do a straight upgrade to 3.1 using spring-security-oauth 1.0.0.M3 or M4:

http://code.google.com/p/spring-security-social/wiki/Usage

Specifically I see this in the Tomcat logs:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration
problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location ...
Offending resource: class path resource [spring/applicationContext.xml]; nested
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected
exception parsing XML document from URL ...; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class
[org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.OAuth2SecurityNamespaceHandler] for namespace
[http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2]: problem with handler class file or
dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/springframework/security/web/util/AntUrlPathMatcher
```

Can someone suggest a solution to the above problem, or point to a reference for using spring-security 3.1 and spring-security-oauth, or else suggest a better alternative to implement oauth2 using spring-security 3.1?

Or if I'm missing a fundamental point of spring-security 3.1, that would also be useful to know.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is yes, it is supported.  Sigh, turns out Spring Security OAuth 1.0.0.M6 is required (or at least sufficient) for Spring Security 3.1:
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?123470-Spring-Security-OAuth-1-0-0-M6-released

This resolved the above BeanDefinitionParsingException.

Comment: So far this looks like the best reference guide: https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/wiki/oauth2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Spring Security OAuth milestone build 1.0.0.M6, and specifically the oauth2 module, supports Spring Security 3.1.0.  It is not yet considered a release.  The [OAuth 2.0 spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2) itself is not final.

The [1.0.0.M6 samples](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/tree/b81d6c19542af63f5940376debc8b626581d6b99/samples/oauth2) appear to be the most accurate and complete reference for implementation.  The full 1.0.0.M6 tag zipball is [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/zipball/1.0.0.M6).

The [OAuth 2 Developers Guide](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/wiki/oauth2) is a good textual reference.  It's not 100% accurate, at least with respect to 1.0.0.M6.  For example, the attribute user-approval-page belongs to authorization-server not authorization-code.

The Maven pom.xml must refer to artifactId spring-security-oauth2 (not spring-security-oauth as in older versions such as 1.0.0.M3).